# ASP.NET MVC4 - Error When Customize Default Accounts Models & Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am in the begining of making a simple website using ASP.NET MVC4 CodeFirst Approach. The web site is built around users who are able to register, make posts etc. The existing `UserProfile` class was modified for the accommodation other fields (ex: FirstName, LastName etc).

When I ran the website I got a similar error:

```
Invalid column name 'FirstName'.
Invalid column name 'LastName'.
Invalid column name 'Phone'.
```

I red that this is because the Database is not updated as the model is updated. So I set the following on the `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax` with the intention of droppnng the database always (at least until I get the hang of it).

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UsersContext>());
        //Other default generated stuff below...
    }
```

I also tryed the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, but both methods didn't drop the database.

Isn't this possible? Why is it? Am I doing some thing wrong?

I believe it would be possible to store the info in a different table and link it to this, but I prefer to keep it in one table.

Also is it a bad idea to add `UserProfiles` to the websites context (lets say: `DatabaseContext` (which has other entities like Posts, Comments etc) and change the `AccountsController` to use `DatabaseContext` instead of `UsersContext`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run `Enable-Migrations` in the Package Manager Console? You should see a migration folder in your project, with a configuration.cs file, ensure you have enabled automatic migrations.

```
public Configuration(){
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    //if you drop columns - consider this carefully...
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```